# Сильно лагает/тормозит при скроле сайт

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

сильно лагает при скроле сайт , пытался отследить ( оптимизировать) ничего не вышло 
http://glavnarzan.ru/  страница досуг самая лагающая

Comment: Ничего не лагает! Или это рекламный ход?

Comment: в хроме , сильно лагает , в мозиле у меня тоже все в порядке

Comment: И как нам вам помочь? Нужны исходники или хотя бы предполагаемая часть кода, отвечающая за неисправность.

Comment: любое место где 3 фотографии в ряд будет лагать , очень странно с галереей  все в порядке

Comment: http://glavnarzan.ru/dosug/ если пролистать в хроме то будет лагать где  4 блока , размер фотографий не причем , самое веселое если поставить одну фотографию для всех блоков лагов не будет , как решить ?

Comment: У вас скорее всего проблема с анимацией блока `.dosug_item`. Попробуйте убрать анимацию вообще и посмотрите, как оно будет работать.

Comment: На хорошей связи не лагает вообще. Возможно, спотыкается на выводе конского контента. Вы зачем фотки 5000x3000 лепите на сайт?